# Android, suggestions on storing temporary data

Tags: android, sqlite

Its an application that is calling the ZXing barcode reader on button push, after scanning in shows you the code and you  can put in an amount (how much you want to order from that product), then you go next scan, so on so on...I need to store this data. In my main window under the scan button, i will have a show scanned list, with all the scanned items plus the amount of each. And i will have a send button which sends a this list in a .txt or a .csv file via bluetooth to PC. And after closing the application with exit button, or with the back key, this list needs to be destroyed , so when i start the application again, there is a fresh, new list. First i thought, on using SQLite, but my costumer wants a simple program, without db. I could just need a few ideas on storing, data else how. Like an array list, but i dont know how hard is it to handle such a storing bethod, with editing or deleting and such. Or directly saving it into a .CSV file? Any idea is welcome.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a Bean class say Product which contains the attributes which you want to display on your list view.
2. Take a ArrayList
3. store the bean objects in arraylist and finally iterate it to do your calculations.
4. To get the CSV, you can call the to string on the instance of arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

IMO using SQLite would be your best option, it does not add that much complexity to your app. Though if you really do not want to use it, [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) is an even simpler API for storing data.